# Validating that 2 fields are equal with Formik and Yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I just started using Formik and Yup.  I'm trying to validate that 2 fields are equal, e.g. an email and password field.  I can't figure out how to do a custom validation.  I tried `oneOf`, `test` and `when`.  The doc is not very extensive

```
 const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email("*Must be a valid email address")
      .required("*Email is required"),
    emailConfirmed: yup
      .string()
      .oneOf([yup.ref("email"), null], "Email must match")
      .required()
    // .when('email', {
    //     is: (val:string)=>{console.log("email is ", val); return !!val;},
    //     then: yup.string().required("*Confirm your email")
    // })
    // .test('email-equals', 'Please re-enter your email to confirm', (value, context) => {
    //     console.log('validating email', value, context.parent.email, (value === context.parent.email));
    //     return value === context.parent.email;
    // })
  });

  const onSubmit = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Submitting", values);
  };
```

Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-smoke-gcujz

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the variable name in object from `emailConfirmed` to `confirmEmail`. Basically yup is unable to find the `emailConfirmed` name input in your form. That's why it was not showing any error. Now your updated yup schema will be looks like below.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email("*Must be a valid email address")
      .required("*Email is required"),
    confirmEmail: yup
      .string()
      .oneOf([yup.ref("email"), null], "Email must match")
      .required()
  });
```

Comment: Thanks!  Stupid typo.  I was staring at this for a day, figuring there was just something about Yup I wasn't understanding

Answer (score 0):

I used this for password and it is working fine for me.

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      password: Yup.string()
        .required(),
      confirmpassword: Yup.string()
        .oneOf([Yup.ref("password"), ''], "password must match")
        .required(),

    }),
```